# Div is not fitting the space available

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I know that this question has already been asked, but I tried everything and I haven't find a solution, so I'm asking again, my apologizes :-).

I'm trying to make my row fill all the remaining screen space of the page, however, my row never shrink, it stays at his initial size.

Notice that my map fits the size of the div.

Here is the code that i'm using :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 mb-12 col-lg-12 ">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4 h-100">

      <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
          Carte des balises
        </h6>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And there is the render of the page : [image: My nice page !]

If someone could give me some clues, I would really appreciate it !

Thanks in advance, :)

Comment: set a `height` on the map element, or add [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) etc

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried to put it to height: 100% and I tried to use height: 100vh; but i don't work..

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what you have to do if we don't see all the page. 
From what I can see, please make sure that the container (the `.row` you have presented) has the desired height. If it doesn't, then you should either make it expand (by using `flex` on the parent and adding `flex-grow: 1` to the container, or by just setting a fixed height - with or without `calc`) .
Next step would be to do the same thing to the map container. Adding `display: flex` to the parent and adding `flex: 1` to the map container is a good healthy way of making the map expand in the available space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="card shadow mb-4 h-100">
```

the **h-100** class here says take 100% height of it's parent and the parent element

```
<div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 mb-12 col-lg-12 ">
```

Does not have a height setup. Also all block label elements in html does not have a height defined out of the box, rather it's depends on it's child.

So what you need to do is set a height on the parent, ex:

In HTML: add a class

```
<div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 mb-12 col-lg-12 map-height">
```

CSS: define the class as below

```
.map-height{
   min-height:calc( 100vh - 300px )
}
```

the 300 px is hard codded here but you need to calculate your header height + the section with 4 big labels height + footer height
Assuming those 3 section has a static height setup.